# removing a widget from angular-gridster

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gridster

I have a grid based  on ng-repeat and an array:

```
$scope.standardItems = [
    { sizeX: 1, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0, i: 0},
    { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 1, i: 1},
    { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 3, i: 2},
    { sizeX: 1, sizeY: 1, row: 1, col: 0, i: 3},
    { sizeX: 1, sizeY: 1, row: 1, col: 1, i: 4},
    { sizeX: 1, sizeY: 1, row: 1, col: 2, i: 5}
];
```

and

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
    <ul>
        <li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in standardItems track by item.i" >
            <div ng-if="$index === item.i && $index === 0" id="item_{{$index}}">

            ....
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to remove one of the wdigets. I tried splicing the array, which resulted in a blank page.
Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like angular-gridster doesn't support this without messing with the original file itself (like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170202/angular-gridster-removing-an-item)) or accessing the DOM item itself, getting the gridster object and removing it via internal function.

Not very "angular way", but that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If any one is still interested, remove track by $index if you have it. Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use some help from here

https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/dashboard

looking at html and js source will resolve your problem